# Alter all columns of a table in mysql database to upper case

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

```
DELIMITER // 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uppercasecol // 

CREATE PROCEDURE uppercasecol(IN tblname VARCHAR(200)) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE oldname VARCHAR(200); 
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='ADM01' AND TABLE_NAME=tblname; 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1; 
OPEN cur; 
REPEAT 
FETCH cur INTO oldname; 
SET @newname = UPPER(oldname); 
#IF newname equals to oldname, do nothing; 
#select 'a' <> 'A'; -> 0 
#select 'a' <> BINARY 'A'; -> 1 
SET @isNotSame = @newname <> BINARY oldname; 
IF NOT done && @isNotSame THEN 
SET @SQL = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',tblname,'` CHANGE COLUMN `',oldname,'` @newname'); 
PREPARE tmpstmt FROM @SQL; 
EXECUTE tmpstmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE tmpstmt; 
END IF; 
UNTIL done END REPEAT; 
CLOSE cur; 
END // 
DELIMITER ;

CALL uppercasecol('USER_MODULE');
```

I am using the above code to convert the column names to upper case but the code is giving error 1604(42000) in CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',tblname,'` CHANGE COLUMN `',oldname,'` @newname'). Can anyone help me out in this...

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE COLUMN `oldname` `newname` datatype(size) NOT NULL;
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',@tblname,'` CHANGE COLUMN `',@oldname,'` @newname');
```